# Validation Form in wiget

Tags: forms, yii2, widget, pjax

I would like to have a form available on every page in my web app. So I created a widget with a form.

```
class AddNewURL extends Widget{

    public $model;


    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if ($this->model === null) {
            $this->model = new ProductUrlForm();
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->render('addNewURLForm', [
            'model' => $this->model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and widget view

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="newURL" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => Url::to(['site/new-url']),
                'options' => ['data' => ['pjax' => true]],
            ]) ?>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new URL</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'url', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block', 'encode' => false]])
                            ->textInput(['maxlength' => false])
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this how I use this widget in my layouts/main.php

```
<?= \app\widgets\AddNewURL::widget() ?>
```

in my *site/new-url* action I have

```
public function actionNewUrl()
    {
        $model = new ProductUrlForm();
        $model->status = STATUS_NEW;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
           //return success message
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

and now when I submit form data goes to my action, the form is reset and that's all. How to show validation error or success message using pjax? In my model I have few custom validation rules.

Maybe there is better solution to use one form on all pages?

Comment: how and where are you calling this widget? add to your question.

Comment: <?= \app\widgets\AddNewURL::widget() ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action `actionNewUrl()` must render view `addNewURLForm` so Pjax can replace old form with new html recieved from the action.

It is better to place your widget, controller and form model to separate module.